# how to add tab(multiple spaces) at each end of a text file using Unix

Tags: unix

I am new to Unix commands. I would just like to ask if adding a tab or should i say multiple spaces right after at the end of each line in Unix is possible?

To give a clearer view of what i am talking about, Supposed i have a text file named **WOW.txt** and it contains:
(Note that WOW.txt is a product from a script that i run. So it is automatically made by a a script)

Wow

Wow2

Wow3

Wow4

And i want to add tabs at each end of line. This is how i want to be an output.

Wow1        KERV

Wow2        KERV

Wow3        KERV

Wow4        KERV

or

Wow1, KERV

Wow2, KERV

Wow3, KERV

Wow4, KERV

Thats i want to be an output. I just want to add the word 'KERV' at each end of a line on my text file. So please somebody help me???

A reply from you would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `AWK` script.
`awk '{printf("%s \t\n", $0)}' your_file.txt > new_file.txt`

Please note that `\t` adds `TABS`. If you want multiple tabs, you can do `\t\t` and `\n` is a `newline` character

If you want to add `KERV` or whatever, add that appropriately, e.g. `"%s, \t KERV : \t\t\n` 
If you do not want your old file, just execute `rm your_file.txt`

Edit: Use the following to not append anything to the link if it is blank--

`awk '{ if (NF > 0) { printf("%s \t\n", $0)} }' your_file.txt > new_file.txt`

Edit: If you want to retain blank lines, but not append anything

`awk '{ if (NF > 0) {printf("%s \t\n", $0)} else {print $0} }' your_file.txt > new_file.txt`

Comment: I got to check on this code. Thank you! I got what i want. But I have a problem. Even the blank lines will also have the KERV. Is it possible that all the lines that have text will be the only ones who will be having KERV.

Example:
Wow1

Wow2

The product after integrating the code is:
Wow1 KERV

     KERV

Wow2   KERV

I just want:
Wow1   KERV


Wow2   KERV

Comment: Hey man. I got this problem. After executing that code that you've given, the blanks in my .txt file has been gone. What i want is to retain the blanks and have '\tKERV' to the line that has text.

Comment: I lack reputation pts yet :). BTW, what if i want to put KERV on the start of each text line?

Comment: Thanks man! When I have the ability to give reputations, I will give give as much as i can =))

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sed` to replace end-of-line (`$`) with whatever it is you are wanting to add.  That will keep the linebreaks as `$` is zero-width.

Comment: What particular code? I didnt know much more about sed command and its syntax. Would you give me a sample code? Sorry i dont know much more about these commands. I am new to Unix. Sorry for being dumb =).

Comment: @user2353329: Consider reading the manual.  Try `man sed` or `info sed`.